# RXJS AngularFire - get Observables from Observable

Tags: angular, firebase, rxjs

I have been trying to get data from Firebase (using Angular).

**Program summary**

It's a small app to store meal recipes, their ingredients to generate cumulated shopping list based on meal planning - daily, weekly, etc.

**What I have:**

**1. Firebase database structure (fragment of it)**

```
    Ingredients (collection)
      Id: string
      Name: string
      Tags: array of string
    Recipes (collection)
      CreatedOn: Timestamp
      MealTitle: string
      MealType: string
      Method: string
      RecipeIngredients (subcollection)
        Id: string
        IngredientId: string
        ExtendedDescription: string
        QTY: number
        UOM: string
```

As you can see *Recipes* collection contains *RecipeIngredients* sub-collection which has *IngredientId* from *Ingredients* collection and some additional data.

**2. Method for getting list of ingredients from *RecipeIngredients* sub-collection for specific recipe**

```
  getRecipeIngredients(recipeId: string): Observable<RecipeIngredient[]> {
    this.recipesCollection = this.afs.collection('Recipes', ref => ref.orderBy('CreatedOn', 'desc'));

    this.recipeIngredients = this.recipesCollection.doc(recipeId).collection('RecipeIngredients').snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(changes => {
        return changes.map(action => {
          const data = action.payload.doc.data() as RecipeIngredient;
          data.Id = action.payload.doc.id;

          return data;
        })
      })
    )

    return this.recipeIngredients;
  }
```

**3. Method for getting specific ingredient based on its Id**

```
getIngredientById(ingredientId: string): Observable<Ingredient> {
    this.ingredientDoc = this.afs.doc<Ingredient>(`Ingredients/${ingredientId}`);

    this.ingredient = this.ingredientDoc.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(action => {
        if (action.payload.exists === false) {
          return null;
        } else {
          const data = action.payload.data() as Ingredient;
          data.Id = action.payload.id;
          return data;
        }
      })
    )

    return this.ingredient;
  }
```

**4. What I want to achieve**

I want to display a list of ingredients for specific recipe in a table containing columns: Ingredient Name, Extended Description, QTY, UOM. The thing is I cannot figure out how to get Ingredient name.
Reasonable solution for me is to do it inside *getRecipeIngredients* an extend its returning result by that field or by whole *Ingredients* collection. I tried RxJS operators like mergeFlat or combineLatest but I got stuck.

I could of course change the database structure but that is also a learning project for me. I believe I'll have this kind of challenge sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was an interesting one, but I think I have it worked out. Please check out my [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mnxvzt). This [decision tree](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/operator-decision-tree) is usually good enough to provide you a function for most Observable scenarios, but I believe this one required a combination of functions.

Relevant code:

```
const recipeId = 'recipe1';
this.recipe$ = this.getRecipeIngredients(recipeId).pipe(concatMap(recipe => {
  console.log('recipe: ', recipe);
  const ingredients$ = recipe.recipeIngredients.map(recipeIngredient => this.getIngredientById(recipeIngredient.id));
  return forkJoin(ingredients$)
    .pipe(map((fullIngredients: any[]) => {
      console.log('fullIngredients: ', fullIngredients);
      fullIngredients.forEach(fullIngredient => {
        recipe.recipeIngredients.forEach(recipeIngredient => {
          if (recipeIngredient.id === fullIngredient.id) {
            recipeIngredient.name = fullIngredient.name;
          }
        });
      });
      return recipe;
  }));
})).pipe(tap(finalResult => console.log('finalResult: ', finalResult)));
```

I included the console logs to help illustrate the state of the data as it's piped around. The main idea here was to use `concatMap` to tell the recipe Observable that I need to map it with another observable once this one is complete, then to use a `forkJoin` to get the full representation of each recipe ingredient, and finally mapping those results back to the original recipe.

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot for helping. Seems it's what I was looking for.